# Probing for device to install to failed on Ubuntu 18;04 Server Installer with AMD X570 motherboard

Tags: 18.04, server, system-installation, amd-ryzen

I have an MSI X570 Gaming Plus motherboard.  CPU/GPU are Ryzen 5 3400G.  It has a 1TB PCIe SSD, and 8 hard drives (2 via an PCIe card).  When I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 Sever on it, I get the message "Unfortunately probing for devices to install to failed.  Please report a bug on Launchpad, and if possible include contents of the /var/log/installer directory.

Not sure how I access that directory to pull the files.  I don't see it on the installer drive.  Thanks!

Comment: Are the disks configured as RAID?

Comment: Ensure the BIOS/firmware is flashed to the latest version from the vendor.  These new mb/CPUs usually need that.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the server installer isn't updated as often as the desktop installer.  So, I used the desktop installer to get Ubuntu on my server, then used tasksel to switch to Ubuntu server.  I hope this helps someone else who runs into this problem in the future.